# Python, using Popen to submit qsub jobs

Tags: python, popen, qsub

I have to write a python script to submit job by using qsub (SGE).

The command I want to execute is in the form:

> qsub -b y /usr/bin/L2prod  filein   fileout

where L2prod is a compiled program (a binary file, this is the reason of the -b y option) and filein/fileout are just strings with the name of the input/output file.
If I open a shell and type the previous line everything goes well.

In my python program I have:

```
... 
 args=['qsub -b y ', L2prod, filein, fileout] 
 log.info('executing: '+' '.join(map(str,args)))
 process=subprocess.Popen(args,shell=True)
...
etc.
```

and the output in the log file is:

> INFO:job_submit:executing: qsub -b y /usr/bin/L2prod
>   /data/L1/20180414-222503_L1.txt  /data/L2/20180414-222503_L2.txt

Looking at the log it seems that the command line is correct, but I got the following error:

> qsub: command required for a binary job

and no job was submitted.

It seems like the "-b y" option was ignored inside the .Popen() method. What am I doing wrong? I thought the shell=True option would have fixed this.

Comment: Try `args=['qsub', '-b', 'y ', L2prod, filein, fileout]`

Comment: It works! Thank you very very much!

Comment: Cool, I posted the same thing as an answer so that others would see it easier.

Answer (score 1):

You must supply each flag as a separate string element of the list. The first line is different.

```
# args=['qsub -b y ', L2prod, filein, fileout]
args=['qsub', '-b', 'y', L2prod, filein, fileout] 
log.info('executing: '+' '.join(map(str,args)))
process=subprocess.Popen(args,shell=False)
```

Why you should avoid using the `shell = True` argument.

https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/a-trap-of-shell-true-in-the-subprocess-module-6db7fc66cdfd

Comment: As I said, it works, thank you! But just to be precise, the correct option for my case is: shell=False

Comment: @fool Thank you. I tweaked my answer and added a relevant link.